# Calculation of the centre coordinate of a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I generated coordinates of four diametrically opposite studs of a crude oil tank. My challenge is how to calculate the centre coordinate of the tank from the coordinates generated so as to derive the radial displacement of the tank. Here are the coordinates:

Stud $1$: $521596.027$mE, $47641.181$mN

Stud $11$: $521663.136$mE, $47641.050$mN.

Stud $6$: $521629.680$mE, $47674.750$mN

Stud $16$: $521629.528$mE, $47697.524$mN.

Stud $1$ is opposite to Stud $11$, and Stud $6$ is opposite to Stud $16$.
Please help me with a simple formula I can understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a formula for you, there is a simple process to try.  You say that these studs are on "diametrically opposite" sides of the tank.  This is the key to solving the problem.

First, find the equations for the lines through the diametrically opposite points.  So, find the equation for the line through Stud 1 and Stud 11 as well as the line through Stud 6 and Stud 16.

Then, compute the intersection of these two lines by solving the two equations for the lines simultaneously.  The coordinates of this intersection are the coordinates of the center of the tank.

---

For future reference, this really doesn't belong in differential-geometry.  This is an algebra/pre-algebra level question.  Be sure to choose your tags carefully.

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed the tags in my edit. Fixed.